# Iterated integral $\int_D \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \ dx \ dy \ dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute $$\int_D \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \ dx \ dy \ dz$$ when $D = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2 \leqslant 1, 0\leqslant z \leqslant 7 \}.$

I managed to get the triple integral

$$\int_{0}^{7}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ dx \ dy \ dz$$

but this isn't trivial to compute at all. $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ seems to define a surface in $\mathbb{R^3}$ that looks like a cone, should I consider polar or cylindrical coordinates here or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cylindrical-coordinates instinct is right. It gives $7\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^1r^2dr$, which I'll leave to you. The shape is a length-$7$ cylinder of radius $1$; we're computing its volume, times the mean of $r$ throughout that volume.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to determine if I should use polar or cylindrical-coordinates? Aren't cylindrical-coordinates just an extension of polars?

Comment: @DanielLi I've edited to call it cylindrical. As you say, cylindrical adds $z$ to the $2$-dimensional polars; the important thing is to decide whether a $3$-dimensional problem is best done in Cartesian, cylindrical or *spherical* polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your figure.  Just let $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and proceed.

[image]